# Class used (in one thread) before being fully initialized (by another)?

Tags: java, multithreading, classloader

Deep inside a library I'm using, there are two mutually referential classes — call them `MR1` and `MR2` — such that `MR1.<clinit>` causes `MR2` to be classloaded and `MR2.<clinit>` causes `MR1` to be classloaded.

The library also has a `Util` class that refers to `MR1`, such that `Util.<clinit>` causes `MR1` to be classloaded.

Lastly, it has a top-level class — call it `TopLevel` — whose constructor has some code like this:

```
Util.callStaticUtilMethod();
MR2.callStaticMR2Method();
```

So the overall dependency graph is something like this:

[image: dependency graph]

I recently encountered a classloader deadlock where two threads both happened to be instantiating `TopLevel` at the same time, with none of these other classes having been loaded yet. One thread got stuck in `MR1.<clinit>`, inside `Util.<clinit>`, in preparation for calling `Util.callStaticUtilMethod()`; the other successfully got past `Util.callStaticUtilMethod()`, and got stuck in `MR2.<clinit>`, in preparation for calling `MR2.callStaticMR2Method()`. (And then a bunch of other threads got stuck on the `MR2.callStaticMR2Method()` line.)

What I don't understand is — if one thread is still stuck, deadlocked, inside `Util.<clinit>`, then how come all the other threads were able to get past the `Util.callStaticUtilMethod()` call? Is it supposed to be possible for a class to be used before it's completely initialized? If so, then how far does this go; for example, could a static final field be accessed by one thread before it's been initialized by another? (From the fact that the other threads weren't able to get past the `MR2.callStaticMR2Method()` call, it seems that this *isn't* a total free-for-all, fortunately; but I can't tell what the rules might be.)

Comment: _the other successfully got past Util.callStaticUtilMethod()_ That should not be possible. How can you tell? You took a thread dump? Show us.

Comment: As always, MCVE please.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Yes, I took a thread dump using `jstack`. I would never have figured this out otherwise. :-) . . . As for creating an MCVE -- I don't know how I would go about reproducing this. The problem has occurred exactly once so far, out of a great many program runs over several months, so it seems to be a rare fluke. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. Your diagram seems to indicate there are two branches within `TopLevel`: one that invokes the `Util` method and one that directly uses something in `MR2`. Is that the case?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Sorry if my question was unclear. `TopLevel` constructor first runs `Util.callStaticUtilMethod()`, then runs `MR2.callStaticMR2Method()`. (Full disclosure: for simplicity of presentation, I factored out a bunch of indirection. `TopLevel` is actually calling other methods that in turn call these methods, and so on. But the constructor never reaches `MR2.callStaticMR2Method()` without having completed `Util.callStaticUtilMethod()`.)

Comment: Do you maybe swallow any exceptions in between?

Comment: So [this snippet](http://ideone.com/ZUM48E) can cause deadlock. It's what I originally thought your code was doing.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Ah, I see. Yeah, I just meant that as a diagram of "what depends on what", rather than as indicating anything about the parallelism of the system. Sorry for the confusion. (And -- no, the library is not swallowing any exceptions.)

Comment: You are not asking for a workaround, so I guess you've already solved the problem? :)

Comment: @bayou.io: A workaround to prevent the deadlock, you mean? Well, I haven't implemented one yet, but it's pretty obvious how to do so, now that I know that the library has this issue. But this question isn't really about the deadlock; it's about the threads that successfully called a method on an incompletely-initialized class.

Comment: Is the static method that got called able to execute successfully despite the class not being completely initialized?  E.g. if it's a self-contained method that doesn't depend on any static state.Perhaps the compiler optimized it out in such a way that it's no longer blocked by the class initializing?  No idea if the compiler can or would do that, but intuitively it seems possible.

Comment: @dimo414: Indeed, the method's behavior is completely determined by its arguments, not by any (static) state. And it doesn't depend on any of the classes involved in the deadlock. So, I think you're probably right. But given that the class hadn't fully loaded yet, I find it bizarre that another thread could come in and apply such an optimization while the original thread was still (unnecessarily?) blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The JLS ([§12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)) states that a static method call will trigger initialization:

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before ... a static method declared by T is invoked.

And it goes on ([§12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)) to describe what should happen when a thread triggers an initialization:

> If ... initialization is in progress for C by some other thread, then ... block the current thread until informed that the in-progress initialization has completed.... Otherwise, record the fact that initialization of the Class object for C is in progress by the current thread.... If the execution of the initializers completes normally ... label the Class object for C as fully initialized, [and] notify all waiting threads.

So *in theory* what you're describing is not possible.  However there is this somewhat vague footnote:

> *Compile-time analysis may, in some cases, be able to eliminate many of the checks that a type has been initialized from the generated code.... Such analysis must, however, fully account for concurrency and for the fact that initialization code is unrestricted.*

Which, as I interpret it, could grant the compiler the freedom to avoid blocking on static method calls that don't rely on any still-initializing state or otherwise impact the memory model.

That said, I tried to replicate the behavior (of a static method returning before its class's initializer did) and have not been able to so.  You shouldn't rule out the possibility that you're simply miss-reading your logs.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I interpret that footnote a bit differently; I take it to mean that the compiler can elide type-has-been-initialized checks in cases where it can statically prove that the type must already have been initialized. (Like how the compiler can elide a cast in cases where it can statically prove that the cast would succeed anyway.) So I don't think that that footnote justifies what I see in the `jstack` output. :-/

Comment: The footnotes are unfortunately vague, but I think what you're describing is specified by the first paragraph. What I quoted (paragraph three) doesn't specify when the compiler can remove initialization checks, just what it has to guarantee if it does so. From that it's not hard to imagine a compiler optimizing out initialization checks for a stateless static method. On the other hand the language appears to be limited to "generated code" which Ch. 12 doesn't really seem to define.  I would say that if you don't think this section justifies the behavior you're seeing, it's clearly not-to-spec.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think the first footnote-paragraph is about the runtime eliding some steps in the initialization procedure, whereas the third footnote-paragraph is about the compiler bypassing the entire procedure. (I think "generated code" just means the output of the compiler's [code generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_generation_%28compiler%29) pass.)